# Dynamic textbox ID in .aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, visibility

I have a question on C#. I use the GridView ItemTemplate to add a textbox to a whole column. I add the ID to the drop down list in ItemTemplate. Therefore, the generated ID of drop down list is 'GridViewID_dropdownListID_number' in each row when I launch the project.

However, I cannot set the drop down list to `.Visible = true` and `.Visible = false` in `.aspx.cs` file. I try to type the 'dropdownListID' and 'GridViewID_dropdownListID_number' to 'Page_Load' function. However, it displays the error message which is under light the statement.

```
'The name 'GridViewID_dropdownListID_0' does not exist in the current content'
```

Can I set the drop down list visible to true and false in .aspx.cs?

P.S I can retrieve the row number by  GridViewRow

Comment: Typically you do this in the template on the .ascx page by having cs code for the value of the visible property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `FindControl`

```
DropdownLIst tvSeries = (DropdownLIst)tableOfTVSeries.Rows[0].Cells[2].FindControl("tvSeriesTableCategoryDropdownLIst");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to do this in the item template of a repeater -- this is typically how this problem is solved:

```
<asp:DataList Runat="server" ...>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="Server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("data") %>'
                    Visible='<%# Container.DataItem("makevisible") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```